# Instead counter returning 0, my code returns error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Creating a Poll module for my Discord.js bot and I keep getting the error :

> Cannot read property 'count' of undefined

when counting the amount of reactions collected.

I'm using this project as a 'Dive in the deep-end' sort of project and have been trying to get by myself with documentation and such, I've read other relatively similar questions and seen the answers provided, but no matter how I try, I cannot implement these answers into my own code.

```js
const reactions5 = await poll5.awaitReactions(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === '\u0031\u20E3' ||
  reaction.emoji.name === '\u0032\u20E3' || 
  reaction.emoji.name === '\u0033\u20E3' || 
  reaction.emoji.name === '\u0034\u20E3' || 
  reaction.emoji.name === '\u0035\u20E3', {
  time: `${sysTime}`
});

const results5 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor('#1dd1a1')
  .setFooter('HiveBot - Poll Module')
  .setTitle('The results have been collected!')
  .setDescription(`**__Question__**
                ${pollQuestion}
                **__Votes__**
                **Voted** :one: **-** ${reactions5.get('\u0031\u20E3').count - 1}
                **Voted** :two: **-** ${reactions5.get('\u0032\u20E3').count - 1}
                **Voted** :three: **-** ${reactions5.get('\u0033\u20E3').count -1}
                **Voted** :four: **-** ${reactions5.get('\u0034\u20E3').count - 1}
                **Voted** :five: **-** ${reactions5.get('\u0035\u20E3').count - 1}`)

message.channel.send(results5);
```

I do the -1 as my bot adds a reaction first to create a template for other users to click the reaction, so I expected it to return 0 but I just get the above mentioned errors.

EDIT: If a user adds a reaction, the count becomes

> 2 - 1 = 1

For some reason when nobody reacts, leaving just the bot reacting (I can see it reacting 0_o), instead of count being

> 1 -1 = 0

I get the above error.

Hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: *"I do the -1 as my bot adds a reaction first to create a template for other users to click the reaction"* Clearly, one of them isn't being added, so `reactions5.get(...)` returns `undefined`. I'm not familiar with that `poll5.awaitReactions` call, but it sure looks like you're waiting for **any** of the five reactions, not all five.

Comment: Please check the update, good sir!

Comment: The update doesn't address my comment above at all. If you debug, you'll find that one of the `reaction5.get(...)` calls returns `undefined.` Your task is to figure out why that is, which we cannot do from just the information above. (Although, again, it doesn't look [to an unschooled eye] like `awaitReactions` will wait for all 5.)

Comment: No, but it does, you said "Clearly, one of them isn't being added" but as my edit explains, the bot adds a reaction.

Comment: Also, you edited that whole last sentence while I was making the edit.

Comment: console.log(reactions5.get('\u0032\u20E3').count) returns 1 my friend

Comment: Yes, I did -- I hit Enter prematurely. You've said twice now that "the bot adds a reaction". Again: Clearly, when the code runs, at least one of those reactions has not been added (yet) (or at least, `reaction5.get(...)` isn't returning it). Just because you expect your bot to do that, doesn't mean A) That it does, or B) That that code doesn't run before all five are added. Rather than dispute the evidence, debug.

Comment: And the *other* four? (BTW: It seems to have escaped your notice: I'm trying to **help** you.)

Comment: I apologise if I'm taking my frustrations out on you, I fully understand you are trying to help, all the other four are exactly the same, if a client doesnt add a reaction it returns 1, if I add a reaction on my actual Discord account, it returns 2. Again, my apologies.

Comment: No worries. Where did you put those `console.log`s? B/c the error is quite clear. I suggest stepping through with a debugger. If for any reason you can't do that, I suggest adding this func just above `const result5 = ...`: ``function getReactionCount(name) { console.log(`Reaction ${name}: ${typeof reaction5.get(name)}`); return reaction5.get(name).count - 1; }`` and then updating the `getDescription` code to use `${getReactionCount('\u0031\u20E3')}` and such. One of them will show `undefined` next to the name, just prior to the error. Beyond that, I can't help I'm afraid.; Good luck with it!

Comment: I placed it right after the `const reactions5` line. Interestingly, with your function, it collected all the bots reactions and returned them to me, but it didn't count any of my reactions submitted on my actual Discord account. I'm not sure whether to laugh or cry. Thanks for putting up with my poor attitude, I'll keep soldiering :D

EDIT: Nope, I'm an idiot, I put the same reaction in every `${}`, brb

Comment: So you're absolutely right, I must have messed up when I did the `console.log`s as with your function is returning `Reaction 2⃣: undefined`!

Answer (score 0):

Next time anyone tries to make sure the ReactionCollector actually picks up the bots reactions, don't `await` the bot making the reactions BEFORE you start watching for them :D

```
        const poll5 = await message.channel.send(embed5);
            poll5.react('\u0031\u20E3');
            poll5.react('\u0032\u20E3');
            poll5.react('\u0033\u20E3');
            poll5.react('\u0034\u20E3');
            poll5.react('\u0035\u20E3');

        const reactions5 = await poll5.awaitReactions(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === '\u0031\u20E3' || reaction.emoji.name === '\u0032\u20E3' || reaction.emoji.name === '\u0033\u20E3' || reaction.emoji.name === '\u0034\u20E3' || reaction.emoji.name === '\u0035\u20E3', { time: `${sysTime}`})
```